# How can I create a desktop GUI application similar to Blender or Maya?

Tags: user-interface, maya, uiwindow, blender-2.67

I would like to create a customized Graphical User Interface Window similar to Blender or Maya GUI window. Please refer this below image:

[image: Blender User Interface Window with tool and menu buttons]

How and where to begin with to design and create a customized GUI window similar to Maya / Blender UI window. Please refer the below image which has video / image preview option and floating buttons and menus:

[image: Maya User Interface Window]

Being a student, instead of using other desktop GUI applications for 3D purposes, can I able to create a Graphical User Interface window similar to Blender / Maya.

Is it possible to create a Desktop Graphical User Interface application? If it is possible then how to begin with to achieve this?

Comment: You could always read the source of Blender. Otherwise this is way too broad and unclear.

Comment: Maya uses `Qt`'s framework for its interface. Good luck!

Comment: This sounds like a good project, but how to build is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Blender has custom GUI tooling that uses OpenGL. You could try learning OpenGL (or Vulkan) and start rendering things, but you should know that creating a GUI library will be a *huge* challenge. You'll need to think about things like dealing with keyboard input, font rendering, text selection...

You'll likely save a lot of time by using an existing GUI library that has solved these problems already, like Qt, Flutter, GTK+. Or you could use the code in Blender, but I'm guessing that it will be harder to find good documentation and community support since it's an internal library.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop applications are usually developed in languages like C# and C++, mostly in any software like Visual studio. Since you need a graphics software, you need a render engine somewhat similar to Blender. Try using OpenGL, or any other render engine of your choice, with these former methods, I mean to combine both the idea of "rendering" and "programming"....It's all about inspirations and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Imho, it won't be an easy task. If you are ready to take up the challenge.

Dear Imgui will be good starting point.